# Phoenix Live View keeps rebuilding a DOM element with phx-update="ignore"

Tags: phoenix-live-view

In my contrived [chat app](https://github.com/ijt/rantclub/tree/a0f83adad7b88652f098fca8acc4485c79b0db9a), I have a timestamp at the bottom that is supposed to tell when the page loaded. Adding chats should not change it, and I included a `phx-update="ignore"` attribute on the div containing the timestamp to prevent that:

```html
<div id="date" phx-hook="Date" phx-update="ignore"></div>
```

However, the timestamp does get updated when chats are added. Here is the initial state:

[image: Before adding chat]

Then I click New Chat and the dialog appears:

[image: Adding chat]

I inspected the DOM and I know that step did not change the timestamp. However, when I press the Save button, the timestamp does change:

[image: After adding chat]

How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Save button in the dialog was triggering a redirect that caused the page to refresh, so I fixed that by replacing the dialog with some widgets with `phx-hook` fields, sending the chats to the server with `pushEvent` in app.js:

index.html.leex

```html
<input id="usernameinput" placeholder="Your name" phx-update="ignore"/>
<input id="chatinput" placeholder="Say something"/>
<button id="newchatbtn" phx-hook="ChatSend">Send</button>
```

app.js:

```js
Hooks.ChatSend = {
    mounted() {
        let viewHook = this
        this.el.addEventListener("click", function() {
            let uni = document.getElementById("usernameinput")
            let ci = document.getElementById("chatinput")
            viewHook.pushEvent("send-chat", {msg: ci.value, username: uni.value})
        })
    }
}
```

index.ex:

```
  @impl true
  def handle_event("send-chat", %{"msg" => msg, "username" => username}, socket) do
    {:ok, c} = Chats.create_chat(%{username: username, body: msg})
    cs = socket.assigns.chats
    cs = cs ++ [c]
    socket = assign(socket, :chats, cs)
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
```

Here is [the commit](https://github.com/ijt/rantclub/commit/5168b1a5cfb017695a7b2f8f46fedf47bcc12082).